# Windows tool for sending complete http body ( including headers ) to server

Tags: http, networking, sockets, soap

I was wondering if anyone knew of a tool where I could send a fully formed HTTP body ( headers & content ) to a web server.  So far the best I've got is putty but was hoping for something where I could look @ and edit the payload then click a button and send it.  ( I could probably write something like this in a couple minutes but was hoping there is an already finished and semi-polished app.

Context:
   I'm testing out a multipart/related soap request and trying to come up with some idea's for editing one element of the payload that's getting eaten somewhere in its journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) is a convenient command-line tool (with Windows binaries available).

Comment: I ended up breaking down and writing a quick & dirty interface to cURL just for testing the SOAP service I was working on.

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) has a request builder in it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) would be perfect. Apparently [this](http://joncraton.org/files/nc111nt.zip) is a windows version.

Comment: This might be a solution except I don't have any c/c++ compilation tools on the windows box, until now I didn't see a point of bothering with it.

Comment: The second link is for a compiled windows binary.